# How can we inject a variable value in production code only for unit testing?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, mern

I have requirement to inject the value for variable **data**.

**index.js**

```
const sideEffect = (arg1, arg2,...) => {
   // It perform complex tasks
   // Involves third-party call, etc
   // Returns the processed output
}

const main = async(args1, args2,...) => {
   const data = await sideEffect(args1, args2, ...);
   // Process the data and returns
   return data;
}

module.exports = {main};
```

**limitations**

1. function **data** is not exported.

I want to do unit testing for **main** function, by injecting the value of **data**, Can it be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

Mocking your function will do the job.

https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions